# Flexbox layout problems - flexbox item spanning multiple rows

Tags: css, mobile, layout, responsive-design, flexbox

I recently posted a similar question however I didn't get an answer I was looking for. Perhaps its because it's not possible. I thought i'd ask again with more detail. I currently have this layout, using flexbox, which I'm happy with.

[image: Mobile Layout]

But I want the ipad to have this layout

[image]

Using this html

```
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <p>image</p>
  <div class="main_content">Main Content</div>
  <div class="gallery_filter">Filter</div>
  <aside class="gallery_upload">Upload</aside>
  <div class="g_ads">Box</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**Without changing** any HTML, is it possible to recreate that layout using flexbox. 
http://jsfiddle.net/V4GMK/

the fiddle isn't pretty, but i hope you get the idea. I just can't seem to get the layout i'm looking for.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm afraid this just isn't possible with Flexbox *without* changing HTML. To get the second layout, you would need a container around the leftmost area, and another around all of the rest. This is more easily solved with Grid Layout, which lacks any reasonable browser support currently: http://caniuse.com/css-grid

Comment: Ahh I was worried about that. I did in the end wrap it round a div tag and it worked that way. Just curious, at which point would you say to yourself, "I will now implement this into websites even though it's not widely supported"? Would you use something that is only 60% supported for example? Thanks @stephenhay

Comment: I use Flexbox now in production. You absolutely can and should. That said, I use it for components (which is where it excels) and not page layout. Usually, fallbacks are simple (display:table, display:inline-block, etc.) but you have to accept that the fallback works a bit differently. For things that won't break a site, I use them as soon as possible after the spec is stable. Flexbox is, Grid isn't.

Answer (score 1):

**WITHOUT** changing the HTML, I think this may be the direction you're wanting to go.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/71vdnop3/),

and here's the code in case that link every breaks:

```
<body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <p>image</p>
    <div class="main_content">Main Content</div>
    <div class="gallery_filter">Filter</div>
    <aside class="gallery_upload">Upload</aside>
    <div class="g_ads">Box</div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height:100%;
}
body > * {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right:10%;
    flex: 1 90%;
}
header {
    background: #ED1B24;
    height:35px;
}
footer {
    background: #7F7F7F;
}

.main_content {
    text-align: left;
    background: #A349A3;
    min-height:200px;
}

.gallery_filter {
    background: #FEAEC9;
}
p {
    background: #FF7F26;
    height:50px;
}
.gallery_upload {
    background: #00A3E8;
}
.g_ads {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    flex: 4 10%;
    background: #7092BF;
    height:100%;
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.gallery_filter, .gallery_upload { flex: 0 2 44%; margin:0; }

.main_content   { flex: 3 90%; }
header          { order: 2; }
p               { order: 3; }
.gallery_filter { order: 4; }
.gallery_upload { order: 5; }
.main_content   { order: 6; }
footer          { order: 7; }
.g_ads          { order: 1; }
```

As you can see, I didn't change your HTML at all.